# HTTP error 403.4 SSL required, although I do not have SSL enabled

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-sbs-2008

I have a SBS 2008. I am trying to enable the existing default DeltaDRL location #2 as shown in the CA-PKI-SnapIn. The error message is: download not possible. The location is `http://pc-nt-mv.hug.local/CertEnroll/hug-PC-NT-MV-CA(1)+.crl`
[image: CA-PKI-SnapIn]

I did create a new virtual directory "CertEnroll" on my default web site that is bound to *:80 (http). I pointed it to `C:\Windows\System32\CertSrv\CertEnroll` where the lists are located. For troubleshooting I granted read permissions to everyone to that folder.

When visiting "http://pc-nt-mv.hug.local/CertEnroll" I get error 403.44 SSL required, although I do not have SSL enabled, as you can see in the image below. To verify that the request is processed by the default website, I deacivated it and got a 404 error, just like I expected.

I need to access /CertEnroll without using SSL. How can I achieve that?

[image: IIS configuration]
(The blacked out information is "remote.hug.com", which is not the real address)

Comment: With an application called "CertEnroll" I wouldn't exclude the application itself requiring SSL/TLS regardless of whether or not SSL is configured, for security purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Could you perhaps rephrase your sentence?

Comment: I set up a fresh SBS 2008 and when adding the virtual directory "CertEnroll" pointing to "C:\Windows\System32\CertSrv\CertEnroll", this was working without any additional configuration. Something redirects my default web site to SSL and I need to remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that having no binding to https/442, the SSL-setting for the web site is not ignored!

It looked like a former colleague added a binding, activated ssl and removed the binding. The setting was greyed out, so I could not deactivate it. Despite being greyed out, it stayed active anyway.

I added a binding, then changed the setting. Now it is working as I expect it.